# Our designer refuses to work because of job official title

Tags: project-management, job-description, title

Our game contains comics to tell part of the story, and our comic designer says that he is not responsible for designing the characters inside the comics because it is the job of the character designer. Is what he said true? As far as I know the comic designer is responsible for everything that is in the comics, regardless of the design content.

And there is no contracts or terms has been set when we started the project (and that did not create any problems between us for years), so we want the default and well-known job duties for both the "comic designer" and the character designer.

Excuse me if I'm not using official job titles here (like a "comic designer"?! is there even such title?) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not about employer-employee working situations, but academic collaboration.

Comment: What have you done in the [past two months](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/194965/our-designer-refuses-to-work-because-of-job-official-title) to improve this issue?

Comment:  we're discussing this subject for the near future work.

Answer (score 4):

> And there is no contracts or terms has been set

You made a major error, and you're now finding out why.

Write a contract that says what you expect your staff/contractors/freelancers to do. You can then negotiate with them around appropriate compensation. Perhaps they won't agree to your terms, in which case you'll need to find someone else - you can't make people do a job they don't want to do.

Comment: We are friends, not manager-employee company, and we work with each other with big tolerance and forgiveness, and every problem we face we solve it together and with good faith, so we just need some clarifications with "comic designer" and "character designer" obligations in game development industry standards, so we can make things right.

Comment: It doesn't seem like either you or your friend is working with "big tolerance and forgiveness" if you're both digging your heels in over the distribution of work.

Comment: We ran into a small misunderstanding, that's just the case, not a big deal.

Comment: If it's not a big deal why are you bringing it up here?

Answer (score 1):

Are you an employer of designers or is this some type of unofficial project?

If you're an employer, you have every right to draft a new contract and re-negotiate. If this employee does not want to sign, then he's effectively no longer employed by you.

If this is just some type of project by a bunch of friends for school, having contracts is absurd. There is no proper chain of command; there is no boss. You contribute in an ad-hoc manner in whatever capacity you can. Sometimes, you may feel like doing a lot of the work. Sometimes, you may feel like there is nothing to do.

Comment: The second case represents us.

Comment: Then your designer friend is a moron. The other 3 can pick up the slack since it is a school project, so learn whatever you can and do your best. When you do peer assessment, just write down why your "designer" didn't design the characters and let the teacher deal with it.